Image slider with diagonal lines separator
I made a 5 image slider container that previews each of the next and previous images. The only problem I have is that I need to make that images are separated by diagonal lines instead of horizontal lines.
This is my code:


const images = document.querySelectorAll(".slider-img")

function clearActiveImage() {
  images.forEach(function(image) {
    image.classList.remove("active-slider");
  });
}

images.forEach(function(image, index) {
  image.onclick = function() {
    event.stopPropagation()
    if (images[index].classList.contains("active-slider")) {
      images[index].classList.remove("active-slider")
    } else {
      clearActiveImage(index)
      images[index].classList.add("active-slider")
    }
  }
})

window.addEventListener("click", () => {
  clearActiveImage()
})
.slider-container {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 150px;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.slider-main {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  aspect-ratio: 1.5 / 1;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.slider-main:has(.img.active) .img:not(.active) {
  filter: grayscale(100%)
}

.slider-img {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% / 5);
  object-fit: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.32, 0, 0.67, 0);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active-slider {
  width: 200%;
}
<div class="slider-container">
  <div class="slider-main">
    <img class="slider-img active-slider" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/mountains-fog-beautiful-night-autumn-260nw-1233564241.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="slider-img" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/sunset-ruby-beach-260nw-35902396.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="slider-img" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/streelights-uttakleiv-village-shine-below-260nw-2333054447.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="slider-img" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/twilight-light-over-isolated-sandwood-260nw-2333055437.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="slider-img" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/silhouette-young-traveler-watched-star-260nw-1730791102.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>



I already tried using "transform: skewX(-20deg)" but then my whole images get distorted. I am attaching an image of how it should look like.


That's the use case of clip-path.
But this might need to use media query to set the css variable --ms  in .slider-img to different value to fit different screen size.


const images = document.querySelectorAll(".slider-img");
const clearActiveImage = ({ target }) => images.forEach((image) => image !== target && image.classList.remove("active-slider"));
images.forEach((image) => image.addEventListener("click", ({ currentTarget }) => currentTarget.classList.toggle("active-slider")));
window.addEventListener("click", clearActiveImage);
.slider-container {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 150px;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.slider-main {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  aspect-ratio: 1.5 / 1;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.slider-main:has(.img.active) .img:not(.active) {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.slider-main:has(.active-slider) .slider-img {
  width: calc(100% / 5);
}

.slider-img {
  --ms: 40px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: var(--i);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% / 5 + var(--ms));
  flex-shrink: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.32, 0, 0.67, 0);
  cursor: pointer;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, calc(100% - var(--ms)) 100%, 0 100%);
}

.slider-img:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: calc(var(--ms) * -1);
}

.slider-img:last-child {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}

.slider-img.active-slider {
  width: calc(100% / 5 + var(--ms) * 4) !important;
}
<div class="slider-container">
  <div class="slider-main">
    <img style="--i: 4" class="slider-img active-slider" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/mountains-fog-beautiful-night-autumn-260nw-1233564241.jpg" alt="">
    <img style="--i: 3" class="slider-img" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/sunset-ruby-beach-260nw-35902396.jpg" alt="">
    <img style="--i: 2" class="slider-img" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/streelights-uttakleiv-village-shine-below-260nw-2333054447.jpg" alt="">
    <img style="--i: 1" class="slider-img" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/twilight-light-over-isolated-sandwood-260nw-2333055437.jpg" alt="">
    <img style="--i: 0" class="slider-img" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/silhouette-young-traveler-watched-star-260nw-1730791102.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>




I hope this works well with your requirements but here I got some issue like outer spacing.
.slider-img:not(.active-slider) {
    transform: skew(-14deg);
}


OP says they've tried skew, but: "then my whole images get distorted".

Edit:
I found a better solution using clip paths.
You can define a polygon clip-path after wrapping each image in a container. The polygon function sets the the vertices of a polygon, letting you customize the shape that's essentially "cut out" of the div.


const images = document.querySelectorAll(".slider-img")

function clearActiveImage() {
  images.forEach(function(image) {
    image.classList.remove("active-slider");
  });
}

images.forEach(function(image, index) {
  image.onclick = function() {
    event.stopPropagation()
    if (images[index].classList.contains("active-slider")) {
      images[index].classList.remove("active-slider")
    } else {
      clearActiveImage(index)
      images[index].classList.add("active-slider")
    }
  }
})

window.addEventListener("click", () => {
  clearActiveImage()
})
    .slider-container {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 150px;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.slider-main {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  aspect-ratio: 1.5 / 1;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 120%;
  height: 100%;
}

.slider-main:has(.img.active) .img:not(.active) {
  filter: grayscale(100%)
}

.slider-img-container {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% / 5);
  object-fit: cover;
  border: none;
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.32, 0, 0.67, 0);
  cursor: pointer;
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0%, 0% 100%, 200% 100%, 200% 0%);
}

.slider-img-container:first-child {
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 100%, 200% 100%, 200% 0%);
}

.active-slider {
  width: 200%;
}

.slider-img {
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  
}
   

 <div class="slider-container">
     <div class="slider-main">
         <div class="slider-img-container">
            <img class="slider-img" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/mountains-fog-beautiful-night-autumn-260nw-1233564241.jpg" alt="">
         </div>
        <div class="slider-img-container">
          <img class="slider-img" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/sunset-ruby-beach-260nw-35902396.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="slider-img-container">
          <img class="slider-img" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/streelights-uttakleiv-village-shine-below-260nw-2333054447.jpg" alt="">
        </div>  
        <div class="slider-img-container">
           <img class="slider-img" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/twilight-light-over-isolated-sandwood-260nw-2333055437.jpg" alt="">       
        </div>
        <div class="slider-img-container">
          <img class="slider-img" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/silhouette-young-traveler-watched-star-260nw-1730791102.jpg" alt="">
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    



Original answer:
You could try something along these lines, where you wrap each image with a div, rotate the container, and counter-rotate the image. My example isn't perfect, but you can play around with it to get your desired effect.


const images = document.querySelectorAll(".slider-img")

function clearActiveImage() {
  images.forEach(function(image) {
    image.classList.remove("active-slider");
  });
}

images.forEach(function(image, index) {
  image.onclick = function() {
    event.stopPropagation()
    if (images[index].classList.contains("active-slider")) {
      images[index].classList.remove("active-slider")
    } else {
      clearActiveImage(index)
      images[index].classList.add("active-slider")
    }
  }
})

window.addEventListener("click", () => {
  clearActiveImage()
})
    .slider-container {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 150px;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.slider-main {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  aspect-ratio: 1.5 / 1;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 120%;
  height: 100%;
}

.slider-main:has(.img.active) .img:not(.active) {
  filter: grayscale(100%)
}

.slider-img-container {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 120%;
  width: calc(150% / 5);
  object-fit: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.32, 0, 0.67, 0);
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: rotate(12deg) translateY(-10%);
}

.active-slider {
  width: 200%;
}

.slider-img {
  transform: rotate(-12deg) translate(-50%, -10%);
  transform-origin: top left;
  
}
   

 <div class="slider-container">
     <div class="slider-main">
         <div class="slider-img-container">
            <img class="slider-img" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/mountains-fog-beautiful-night-autumn-260nw-1233564241.jpg" alt="">
         </div>
        <div class="slider-img-container">
          <img class="slider-img" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/sunset-ruby-beach-260nw-35902396.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="slider-img-container">
          <img class="slider-img" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/streelights-uttakleiv-village-shine-below-260nw-2333054447.jpg" alt="">
        </div>  
        <div class="slider-img-container">
           <img class="slider-img" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/twilight-light-over-isolated-sandwood-260nw-2333055437.jpg" alt="">       
        </div>
        <div class="slider-img-container">
          <img class="slider-img" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/silhouette-young-traveler-watched-star-260nw-1730791102.jpg" alt="">
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    



